# ABPeoplePicker calls the number chosen

Tags: iphone, abpeoplepickerview

I'm using the people picker so the user can choose a phone number from their contacts to use in the app.

When the user clicks on the number, the phone app opens and that number is called...

Is there any way to stop this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at shouldPerformDefaultActionForPerson:

```
- (BOOL)personViewController:(ABPersonViewController *)personViewController shouldPerformDefaultActionForPerson:(ABRecordRef)aPerson 
                    property:(ABPropertyID)property identifier:(ABMultiValueIdentifier)identifierForValue {
            if(property == kABPersonPhoneProperty) {
              //save the number
              return NO;
            }
        return YES;
        }
```

--EDIT--

The above method is for ABPersonViewController which I mistook for ABPeoplePicker. The logic for ABPeoplePicker is the same as above only you would use this delegate call back instead:

```
- (BOOL)peoplePickerNavigationController:(ABPeoplePickerNavigationController *)peoplePicker shouldContinueAfterSelectingPerson:(ABRecordRef)person property:(ABPropertyID)property identifier:(ABMultiValueIdentifier)identifier
```

Answer (score 0):

I just forgot to return NO in the shouldContinueAfterSelectingPerson: method, I don't know where you got shouldPerformDecaultActionForPerson: from, it's not one of the delegation methods